# Javascript foreach gives me same value every time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

i have a foreach function in javascript to upload multiple files at once and display them in a div along with their percentages uploaded. my problem i am only testing right now and i made a variable to get the name of each file in the input but there is multiple files in one input so i alert the variable i made to get the name of the file but i get alerted the last file every time. Here is my Code below.

```
$('#File').change(function(event) {
        for(I = 0; I < this.files.length; I++)
        {
            var Name = this.files[I].name;
            var Type = this.files[I].type;
            var Size = this.files[I].size;

            var Add = '';
            Add += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:60%;">'+Name+'</div>';
            Add += '<div id="UpPer" class="UploadLabel" style="width:10%;">0%</div>';
            Add += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">N/A</div>';
            Add += '<div class="UploadLabel" style="width:15%;">'+Type+'</div>';
            $('#UploadContent').append(Add);

            var Data = new FormData();
            Data.append('File[]', this.files[I]);
            var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            Request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                if(event.lengthComputable)
                {
                    var Percent = event.loaded / event.total;
                    alert(Name);
                }
            });

            Request.open('POST', 'Upload/Upload.php');
            Request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
            Request.send(Data);
            $('#UploadModal').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
```

look in the progress function and i alerted the Name variable.

Comment: You're not using a foreach loop.

Comment: Your variable `I` is currently implicitly global. You should probably declare it using `var I;` above the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your variable `Name` has the value of end of loop when the callback is called.

You can protect this variable with an immediately called function :

```
(function(Name){
    Request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
         if(event.lengthComputable){
               var Percent = event.loaded / event.total;
               alert(Name);
         }
    });
})(Name);
```

This intermediate function creates a scope in which the new Name variable is protected.

Alternatively, if you need other the variables, you could declare a function taking `I` around the whole content of the loop.

You could also have used jQuery `each` :

```
$.each(this.files, function(I) {
      // the content of your loop
});
```

The use of a function called by `each` would also have created a scope for the needed value of Name.

Comment: that works but it now alerts the same name twice and then moves to the next name and alerts that twice and so on...

Comment: @MoussaHarajli That's normal : the [progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) can very well be sent more than once.